# Retrieving Blank Excel upon attaching excel in Mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Im using this code to Send a Mail with excel attachment from gridview, it works fine for the mail part but the excel attachment is always blank i have already debugged the code and sure that the datasource of the Gridview passes the data it needed to the gridview, it seems that im not rendering the gridview to excel right. the whole process is in a for each loop depending on the number of elements inside the foreach..

am i missing some code?

```
protected void MailButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<FOAM> foamList = new List<FOAM>(servs.GetAreaList());
    foreach (FOAM foam in foamList)
    {
        Session["Area"] = foam.ItemAreaCode;
        Session["Principal"] = foam.PrincipalAmount;
        Session["Accountability"] = foam.AccountableAmount;
        Session["Count"] = foam.ItemCount;

        foamdetails.ItemAreaCode = foam.ItemAreaCode;
        FOAMTemplateGridview.DataSource = servs.GetFoamAsOfUnsettledforAOM(foamdetails);
        FOAMTemplateGridview.DataBind();

        StringWriter _writer = new StringWriter();
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("AreaManagersMail.aspx", _writer);

        StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
        FOAMTemplateGridview.RenderControl(hw);

        MailMessage newMail = new MailMessage();
        newMail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        newMail.To.Add("test@test.com");
        newMail.Subject = "Unsettled FOAM As of " + DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + "-A" + foam.ItemAreaCode;

        System.Text.Encoding Enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
        byte[] mBArray = Enc.GetBytes(stw.ToString());
        System.IO.MemoryStream mAtt = new System.IO.MemoryStream(mBArray, false);

        newMail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(mAtt, "test.xls"));
        newMail.Body = _writer.ToString();
        newMail.From = new MailAddress("test@test.com");
        newMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient SmtpSender = new SmtpClient();
        SmtpSender.Port = 25;
        SmtpSender.Host = "MailHost";
        SmtpSender.Send(newMail);

        newMail.Dispose();
    }


}
```

Comment: try debugging and check whether you are getting the `data in the debugger` or not

Comment: @nadeem yes i have tried and sure that i do get data from the data source of the gridview but upon checking the mBarray it retrieves zero dimensions.

Comment: @User6675636b20796f7521 From where do you get data for which will be written in excel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well found the answer myself,

instead of directly rendering the gridview i passed the value of the gridview in a TABLE then the table is the one i used for rendering,

Sample below:

```
    Table table = new Table();     
    table.Rows.AddAt(3, FOAMTemplateGridview.HeaderRow);

                foreach (GridViewRow row in FOAMTemplateGridview.Rows)
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                    foreach (TableCell tc in row.Cells)
                    {
                        switch (index)
                        {

                            case 0: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                                break;
                            case 1: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                                break;
                            case 2: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                                break;
                            case 3: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                                break;
                            case 4: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                                break;
                            case 5: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                                break;
                            case 6: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                                break;
                            case 7: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                                break;
                            case 8: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                                break;
                            case 9: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                                break;
                            case 10: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                                break;
                            case 11: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                                break;
                            case 12: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                                break;
                            case 13: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                                break;
                            case 14: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                                break;
                            case 15: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                                break;
                            case 16: tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                                break;
                        }
                        tc.Attributes.Add("class", "text");
                        tc.BorderStyle = System.Web.UI.WebControls.BorderStyle.Solid;
                        tc.BorderColor = Color.Black;
                        tc.Font.Name = "Arial";
                        tc.Font.Size = 10;
                        index++;
                    }

                }
            StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
            hw.WriteLine(@"<style>.text { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>");
            table.RenderControl(hw);

            MailMessage newMail = new MailMessage();
            newMail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            newMail.To.Add(foam.AomMail);
            newMail.Subject = "Subject";
            System.Text.Encoding Enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
            byte[] mBArray = Enc.GetBytes(stw.ToString());
            System.IO.MemoryStream mAtt = new System.IO.MemoryStream(mBArray, false);
            newMail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(mAtt, "sales.xls"));
```

Then there you go i can attach the right file upon sending mail rather than the blank.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting blank excel because you are getting `bytes` from `stw` which is defined but it has never been given a value.

> `stw` is only a new object with no value that's why you are getting `0
>   bytes array` in `mBArray`.

And than you assigned `mAtt = new System.IO.MemoryStream(mBArray, false);`. So as `mBArray` is empty so is `mAtt` and you have created file from `mAtt` which is empty that's why you are getting empty file in email. I guess you need to change this line

```
byte[] mBArray = Enc.GetBytes(stw.ToString());
```

to

```
byte[] mBArray = Enc.GetBytes(_writer.ToString());
```